# Dart conditional (ternary) operator using 4 indent instead of 2

Tags: flutter, dart, dartfmt

Hello i want to ask is there a way to change indent used in conditional operator in dart?
i have code like this

[image]

after isDiscount == true dart add 4 indent instead of 2
is there a way to change it so i can manage make dart use 2 indent instead

i used android studio as my editor

here i also have another example for textstyle color that use indent 4

[image]

Comment: sorry but its not related to code but its code formatting , which mean its appearance that bother me

Comment: you have both ? and the beginning of a list with (.  It has to indent twice.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i also have other example i put in textstyle color like this. color: isDiscount ? CustomColor.colorRedSoft : isPriceMin ? CustomColor.colorButtonOrange : textColor . this also indent 4 space instead and there's no ( there

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
condition
? Widget
: condition
? Widget
: condition
? Widget
: Widget
```

Comment: uhh i alraedy used conditional operator there, it is indent from dart that bother me that give me 4 indent when i used auto format somehow, i want to make it to use 2 indent